# Python: Create a range of ordered numbers skipping the inverse of every Nth through Nth+D number

Tags: python, range, slice, skip

Greetings stackoverflow friends. I've decided to get a little wild this evening and party with for loops to iterate through a list I have created.

It appears the party has been pooped on, though, as the manner through which I would like to create a range is not readily apparent, neither through research nor playing around, and proving bothersome

The Desire: I would like to create a range of numbers much in a similar way that a range is usually created... by specifying range(start, stop, step) but with the minor alteration that I may additionally specify a step 'sweep' value such that range performed more like range(start, stop, step:sweep)

That is to say, if the glorious function above existed it could be used as following;

```
range(0,16,3:5)
# [0,3,4,5,8,9,10,13,14,15]
```

Another example!

```
range(0,24,2:9)
# [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23]
```

Yet another!

```
range(0,24,3:9)
# [0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,21,22,23]
```

Last one.

```
swept_range(5,20,3,4)
# [7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19]
```

In English, I desire a simple way to create a range of ordered numbers holding on to every Nth through Nth + D number group where D is some positive number.

I've looked at slices to no avail.

I know MATLAB can succinctly do this but wasn't sure this exists in Python - does anyone?

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. What is _sweep_?

Comment: Sweep may not be the best word... redefining skip and sweep as 'skip start' and 'skip end' respectively is better but not much more true to my intention. Should be understandable by reading the examples though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this generator, using modular arithmetic:

```
def swept_range(start, stop, step=1, sweep=1):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        if not 0 < i % sweep < step:
            yield i
```

You could also use a list comprehension, if you need a sequence, rather than an iterator:

```
def swept_range(start, stop, step=1, sweep=1):
    return [i for i in range(start, stop) if not 0 < i % sweep < step]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look! This is exactly what I needed as well

Comment: swept_range(5, 20, 3, 4) =  [7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19]. This is correct

Answer (score 2):

```
def yrange(st, sp, N, D):
    return [st] + [j for i in range(st,sp,D) for j in range(i+N,i+D+1) if j < sp]

print yrange(0, 16, 3, 5)
# [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
print yrange(0, 24, 2, 9)
# [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23]
print yrange(0, 24, 3, 9)
# [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: Awesome! That is a glorious solution. This being my first inquiry of this sort I am officially flabbergasted to get useful information in a conversation from complete (Awesome) strangers as quickly as I did. You RULE! Thank you!

Comment: Execution time for swept_range(0,24,3,9) 1.49443458973e-05 s. 
Execution time for y_range(0,24,3,9) 9.0571793317e-06 s. 
Output  [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23]

Comment: @user3491991 What should be the output for `yrange(5, 20, 3, 4)`?

Comment: The output for the desired function with st=5, sp=20, N=3, and D=4 is [7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19] which, having now checked, is not the output of yrange(5, 20, 3, 4) but rather the output of swept_range(5, 20, 3, 4) courtesy of @Blckknght. Though swept_range is the answer I will accept please know the effort to find a solution and follow up to verify that solution is forever noted. I will do better to be more specific in future posts. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def srange(start, stop, step=1, sweep=0):
    if sweep < 0 :
        raise Exception("sweep needs to be positive.")
    STEPPING = 0
    SWEEPING = 1
    state = STEPPING
    next = start
    res = []
    while next < stop:
             res.append(next)

             #ignores state if sweep is 0
             if state == STEPPING or sweep == 0 :
                        state = SWEEPING
                        next = next + step
             elif state == SWEEPING :
                        next = next + 1      
                        if next % sweep == 0:
                                 state = STEPPING
    return res
```

Comment: Stackoverflow rocks! Thank you for your help